# Using a loop to create multiple childs of the same bitmap (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a bitmap that I want more than one of at different positions on the stage. I'd guess that this is achievable using a loop but I'm not sure how.

Currently I have:

```
[[Embed(source="../lib/Spikes.png")] //Spikes
    public var SpikesImage:Class;

public var spikesBitmap:Bitmap = new SpikesImage();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a loop to create multiple instances of `SpikesImage`:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var spikes:Bitmap = new SpikesImage();
    spikes.x = i * spikes.width;

    addChild(spikes);
}
```

Though this would consume far more memory than if you were to have one Bitmap on the stage, and use [`copyPixels()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29) to draw the data of `SpikesImage` onto that multiple times.

An example of that:

```
var screen:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
screen.bitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);

var spikes:Bitmap = new SpikesImage();
var drawPosition:Point = new Point();
var drawRect:Rectangle = spikes.bitmapData.rect;

for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    drawPosition.x = i * spikes.width;

    screen.bitmapData.copyPixels(
        spikes.bitmapData,
        drawRect,
        drawPosition
    );
}

addChild(screen);
```

The downfall of this approach however is that you lose the ability to transform the graphics in any way (rotate, scale).

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example of how I could use copyPixels()?

Comment: @Craig Sure, take a look over that.

Comment: Also, I don't see how the loop example you given works. variable i is just an integer, you can't assign an x position to an integer.

Comment: @Craig I see what you mean, that was a typo (I'm used to referring to objects as `i` in a `foreach`).

Comment: I don't see how it will create an instance of the bitmap though. How I read it, you're using addChild() and passing an integer.

Comment: I've got it now. Thanks so much for the help :)